# In Excel Charting, have one series out of four limit the data points

Tags: excel, vba, charts, linegraph

I want to plot on a line graph in Excel using VBA, but can't get the below to format correctly to look like an Excel worksheet.  Numbers represent values for Feb through June. No values yet in months July & Aug.

```
                "Feb"   "Mar"   "Apr"   "May"   "June  "July" "Aug"
Obs to Go      / 112  /  108  /  104  /   99  /   94 /
Plan Reserve   /  23  /   22  /   21  /   20  /   19 /
Actual Reserve /  29  /   30  /   31  /   37  /   37 /
Reserve Value  /  13  /   15  /   16  /   17  /   18 /
```

I want to plot all 4 items on line graphs-Layout 5 (Ob's to go, Plan Reserve, Actual Reserve Balance, Reserve $ Above/Below). But on "Actual Reserve" I want it to only take the last two most recent months of data and only plot those 2 points on a line graph, with the others line graphs plotting data from Feb through June.

How can I automatically get excel to pick up only the last 2 most recent months for "Actual Reserve Balance" each month and drop off the older months of data while still showing the others since inception (beginning with Feb to most current month).  Each month I will populate the data for the current month i.e. July, Aug, Sept etc. but will want the graph to only plot the most 2 current months for "Actual Reserve" line.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this with type 5, xlLineMarkersStacked.  It will display the other points, even if you set DisplayBlanksAs to xlNotPlotted.